# Combine two factors using translation table

Tags: r, matrix

I'm trying to combine two factor-variables `A`, `B` through a "translation table", like this:

```
#example factors:
A <- factor(c("a","d","b"),levels=letters[1:6])
B <- factor(c("b","e","d"),levels=letters[1:5])

#translation table (columns correspond to A, rows to B):
m <- structure(c(1L, 5L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 3L, 3L, 8L, 6L, 9L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 
                 9L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 0L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 6L, 
                 3L), .Dim = 5:6, .Dimnames = list(c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), 
                                                   c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")))
#  a b c d e f
#a 1 3 5 2 4 1
#b 5 3 4 6 5 1
#c 9 8 7 5 0 7
#d 9 6 9 5 7 6
#e 9 9 5 2 4 3
```

I would like to get `C <- c(5, 2, 6)` as the result for the example factors.

My first try would be `C <- m[A,B]`, but this results in something else (it doesn't go through the lists pair-wise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your matrix is `m`, and your factors are `A` and `B`:

```
m[cbind(B, A)]
```

Comment: cbind also seems to work for more than two variables, that is great! thanks.